# Search through all files including dependencies

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a folder opened in Visual Studio Code, and a file in that folder that I am debugging. I am trying to search for a specific function that has been imported from different project. Apologies for the lack of proper terms, for better explanation, see below

```
- folder-with-my-projects
    - project1
        -file-I-am-debugging.py (function X is imported)
    - project2
        -file-containing-function-X.py
```

I want to be able to search for function X, when I have the project 1 opened in the IDE. These are all python projects, if that matters. Right now, the search only looks through files in project1 folder and completely ignores anything else. For example, Pycharm's *Find in Files* does exactly what I need. Is there a way to have this functionality in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Sorry, but could you provide a screenshot of the search in the VSCode and the Pycharm, and your import code? PyCharm will not search everywhere except you have included the path.

Answer (score 0):

Open VScode in a directory that is a parent to both directories and search from there.

Alternatively, you should be able to use multi-use workspaces to add a folder outside your current directory into your project space which should allow you to search it. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces

Comment: I am aware about this possibility, the thing is I would like it to work from the current folder not the parent one. In Pycharm you don't have to open the parent folder either.

Comment: I did not think it was possible with VScode but you may look into "Multi-root Workspaces". https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces

Comment: Interesting, I will definitely check that one out. Thank you!